# Product image not displaying in product page

Tags: image, magento, product

![enter image description here][1]Product image not displaying in product page of magento. Where as its showing in list and grid. It is due to an extension which i installed and uninstalled, since that the product image is not showing up, Even the view.phtml is not called, Please any suggestions ...

Comment: view.phtml not called?which file called then?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your html is rendering or not in xml, you can find this from below file.

app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/catalog.xml

Xml block :

```
    <!-- Category default layout -->
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

if it is there.. then check your view.phtml file.

app/design/frontend/package/theme/catalog/product/view.phtml

Code for the display image.

```
    <div class="product-img-box">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: please let me see your catalog.xml so i will have a more idea.